# Best Practice: Calling separate Web-API Service from Single Page Application (SPA)

Tags: azure, controller, cors, single-page-application

Hy all

We are discussing around the architecture of the following scenario:

- Single Page Application (JavaScript driven Html5 Application with ASP.NET WebAPI)
- Separate REST Service (WebAPI only) with BusinessLogic, DAL, DataBase-Connectivity
- Security over Azure AD (ADAL)

What is the the Way to call the REST-Service from the Single Page Application?

At the moment we are seeing to possibilities:

1) Calling the REST-Service directly from the client (Browser) via CORS:

Client (Browser) -> REST-Service

...like in this example: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-WebAPI-AngularJS-DotNet

2) Calling the WebAPI-Service from the Single Page Application, which then calls the REST-Service:

Client (Browser) -> WebAPI SPA -> REST-Service

For the first variant, we see some security questions.
Is it generally save to do it like this?
What if the REST-Service is in a internal Network and the SPA in the DMZ?

For the second variant, what are best practices here? Because we need something like this for our controllers:

SPA Controller Example:

```
//GET /api/Models
public IQueryable<Model> Get()
{
   // Create an HttpClient instance
   var resp = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:9472/api/Models").Result;
            var result = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Model>>().Result.AsQueryable();
   return result;
}
```

REST-Service (localhost:9472) Controller Example:

```
//GET /api/Models
public IQueryable<Model> Get(){
   return _repository.GetAllModels();
}
```

-> Is this the right way to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just finished a large enterprise style SPA using, nearly, exactly the architecture you describe in option 1.

Generally speaking keep things simple. More points of failure just introduce increased risk in terms of maintenance, uptime, scalability etc. If you don't **need** a proxy service don't introduce it for the sake of it - your service will be no less secure.

Can you explain your security concerns about option 1, and hopefully I can alleviate them for you?

-- Edit --

I see your point on SPA being within the DMZ and the RESTful service being internal, for your SPA to be able to call the RESTful service you will require a way to expose this to the outside world. Depending on what security you already have in place, it could be a case of just moving this into the DMZ otherwise you are going to need to proxy in-between the outside world and your internal rest service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We decided to use the first scenario, because we have the DMZ, so we need the proxy in-between. I've posted a follow-up question regarding the authentification -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511094/howto-call-from-spa-angularjs-based-azure-ad-protected-to-webapi-webapi-onl