# HowTo: Call from SPA (AngularJS based, Azure AD Protected) to WebAPI (WebAPI only, Azure AD Protected)

Tags: rest, azure, active-directory, single-page-application

Hy All

We have the following Scenario:

- Single Page Application (AngularJS based, Azure-AD protected). Like in this sample: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/SinglePageApp-AngularJS-DotNet
- Separate REST Service (WebAPI only, Azure-AD protected) with BusinessLogic, DAL, DataBase-Connectivity
- Security over Azure AD (ADAL)

Azure-Configuration:

- Two WebApps (SPA and REST Service)
- One Directory with the above two Web-Apps as Applications
- SPA is allowed to call the REST Service

Security-Configuration of the SPA:

```
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SPAAudience"],
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
            });
    }
```

...the same for the Web-API (with the WebAPIAudience).

Flow:

- Client (Browser, Internet) -> WebAPI SPA (DMZ) -> REST-Service (Internal)

We cannot use Cors and need the above proxy-like Scenario, because the REST-Service is internal.

My Question:

- How can we call the WebAPI REST Service from the SPA with the signed-in user's permissions (from the SPA Authentification)?

Thanks for your help!

Peter

**Edit:**
What I've found out so far:

- Oauth2 is using the application identity for Authentication (not the User)

What we want to achieve at the end:

- A role based access control (RBAC) on the REST-Service Side

Questions:

- Can we use Oauth2 for that purpose (RBAC) or do we need OpenID Connect like in the example: WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet (Azure AD Example)
- Can we use Oauth2 for calling the REST-Service from the SPA with  the Application credentials or do we need OpenID Connect like in this example: WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-AppIdentity-DotNet (Azure AD Example)
- What is the best practice in this Scenario?

Thanks.